# Search and sync files from remote systems

Tags: linux, shell, rsync, command-line-interface

I have a folderA remotely which has 2 subfolders folderB and folderC.I have to search for my

file where it is located in the 2 subfolders(folderB and folderC) and should copy it.

Is it possible with rsync and a script like thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use find over ssh:

```
scp user@hostname:`ssh user@hostname "find folderA -name \"targetFile\" "` .
```

This opens up two SSH connections, so you'll be prompted for the password twice unless you've set up unprotected key-files.

Comment: It doesn't work if file name including spaces.

Comment: It will if you escape your spaces with a '\' character

Comment: It is not a concrete filename. How do you escape it from your above command?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using rsync just exclude everything, then only include the name of the file you want:

```
$ rsync --exclude="*" --include="filename" -e ssh user@remote:path/to/folderA/ .
```